# How to create a backup of my email?

Tags: email, backup, imap

I need to create a backup of my emails which sometime in the future I can restore by uploading them to a new server. Not synchronize, but create a backup.

Also, at the moment there's only one server which I access via IMAP, meaning, there's no other server I can synchronize my emails with. When I need to restore them from a backup, there'll be also only one server -- a new one. This also implies that I can't use synchronization.

If this goal requires building a custom application and knowledge of IMAP protocol -- that's ok.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using any sofware in particular to view your mail?

Comment: @Icewine, no...

Comment: https://github.com/amenonsen/gmail-mirror (nothing really gmail-specific there, despite the name)